# How to make a UIImageView photo disappear after a time interval in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I am working on a camera app for segmentation and I managed to capture the live photo to show in a UIImageView as thumbnail. Now I want it to disappear within 3 seconds if the user does not touch (like IOS camera behavior when the picture is taken). Could you please help me how to achieve? Please see the related part of my code below. Many thanks in advance.

```
// MARK: -- Action to Capture Photo

extension ViewController {
    
    @IBAction func photoButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
        CameraManager.shared.capture { [weak self] (pixelBuffer, sampleBuffer) in
            self?.handleCameraOutput(pixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, onFinish: { (image) in
                self?.imagePreview.image = image
                
                let pngData = image!.pngData()
                let compressedData = UIImage(data: pngData!)
                self!.writeToPhotoAlbum(image: compressedData!)

            })
        }
                
    }
        
        func writeToPhotoAlbum(image: UIImage) {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(saveError), nil)
    
        }

        @objc func saveError(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
            
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:)` method like this:

```
var noUserInteractionOnImage = true // toggle this if user interacts with image

@IBAction func photoButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    CameraManager.shared.capture { [weak self] (pixelBuffer, sampleBuffer) in
        self?.handleCameraOutput(pixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, onFinish: { (image) in
            //...
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                if self?.noUserInteractionOnImage == true {
                    self?.imagePreview.image = nil
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: cool... It worked well. Many thanks for your kind support

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped then mark as right and upvote.

Comment: I had done it but my action points were not enough to show my votes. Now I have exceeded the threshold and able to upvote 